# Required String parameter 'token' is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf in my application, I'm trying implement 'token CSRF' in Controller and thymeleaf file to reset password and protect by CSRF:

my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sdsc0004")
public class SdsPasswordRegController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SdsPasswordRegController.class);

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@ModelAttribute("customer")
public SdsPasswordRegForm passwordReset() {
  return new SdsPasswordRegForm();
}

@GetMapping
public String getUpdatePassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
@RequestParam("token") String token, Model model) {

   Customer checkTokenUser = customerService.findByConfirmationTokenCSRF(token); 
   // No token found in DB
    if(checkTokenUser == null) {
      // modelAndView.addObject("invalidToken", "Oops!  This is an invalid confirmation link.");
      LOGGER.info("invalid Token");
      model.addAttribute("invalidToken", "can not verify token !!");
    }
    else {
       model.addAttribute("confirmationToken", checkTokenUser.getConfirmationToken());
      LOGGER.info("invalid Token", checkTokenUser.getConfirmationToken());
    }

    LOGGER.info("Loading submit form successfully");
    model.addAttribute("customer", customer);

    return "sdsc0004";
  }

  @PostMapping
  public String setUpdatePassword(@ModelAttribute("customer") @Validated SdsPasswordRegForm customer, 
BindingResult result, Model model, @RequestParam Map requestParams) {

 Customer customerDTO = new Customer();  
 // boolean resetOrUpdatePassword = customerService.save(customer.getNewPassword());  

 if (result.hasErrors()) {
  LOGGER.info("Submit form: confirm submit password success !!");
    return "sdsc0004";
  } 
  else {
    // customer.setSdsUserMgmtDto(customerDTO.setIsLocked(false));
    customerDTO.setIsLocked(true);  
    customerDTO.setConfirmationToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());  

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("token generate automatic: " + customerDTO.getConfirmationToken());

    // customerService.save(customer.getNewPassword());  

    return "redirect:/sdsc0005";
   }
  }    
 }
```

my HTML:

```
<div th:if="${invalidToken}" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:text=${invalidToken}></div> 

    <form th:if="!${invalidToken}" th:action="@{/sdsc0004}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" th:value=${confirmationToken}  >

        <div style="margin-top: 2em">   
            <div class="row">                   
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                </div> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>                          
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-5" style="background: #f2f2f2;">
                                <p>
                                <input type="password" style="width: 100%;" name="newPassword" th:value="*{newPassword}" placeholder="New password" />
                                <div class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('newPassword')}" th:errors="*{newPassword}"></div>
                                </p>
                                </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-5" style="background: #f2f2f2;">
                                <p>
                                    <input type="password" style="width: 100%;" name="confirmNewPassword" th:value="*{confirmNewPassword}" placeholder="Confirm new password" />
                                    <div class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmNewPassword')}" th:errors="*{confirmNewPassword}"></div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                            </div> 

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-5" style="background: #f2f2f2;">                                       
                            <button type="submit" class="logoff-btn" style="width: 100%; padding: 3%; margin: 0">Reset</button>
                        </div>      
                    </div>                                                                                    
                </div>   
    </form>
```

When I build and it happen an error following as:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'token' is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'token' is not present
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
```

How to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you actually add the token as a request parameter, but, like all other values, it is part of the Form Model. You might want to check the contents of your Model first.

EDIT: For further development it's a good idea to debug and explore your ServletRequest. It shows the called URL, the request headers and body. IF you actually send data from your client, you'll find it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with your business logic. You send the "token" with "post" method in thymeleaf, but requires "token" param in "@GetMapping".